# Keep first occurrence in duplicated values in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, iteritems

Having duplicated values in dictionary such as the following:

```
dict_numbers={'one':['one', 'first','uno', 'une'],
            'zero':['zero','nothing','cero'],
            'first':['one', 'first','uno', 'une'],
            'dos':['two','second','dos', 'segundo','deux'],
            'three':['three','tres','third','tercero'],
            'second':['two','second','dos','segundo','deux'],
            'forth':['four','forth', 'cuatro','cuarto'],
            'two': ['two','second','dos', 'segundo','deux'],
            'segundo':['two','second','dos', 'segundo','deux']}
```

I'd like to get the first occurrences of keys that have duplicated values. Notice, that the dictionary does not have duplicated keys, but duplicated values. In this example, I would get a list keeping the first occurrence of duplicated values:

```
list_numbers_no_duplicates=['one','zero','dos','three','forth']
```

`first` key is removed because `one` has already the same values.
`second` key is removed because `dos` has already the same values.
`two` key is removed because `dos` has already the same values.

How to keep track of the several duplicates in the values of keys?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you explain `'dos'` and  `'forth'` in the expected output?

Comment: `dos` is the first key with the value `['two','second','dos', 'segundo','deux']`, `two` and `segundo` keys are also in the dictionary, but they have the same value  `['two','second','dos', 'segundo','deux']`, they appear after `dos`, so they are not part of the final_list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully I understood correctly your goal. The following uses `chain` from the ever-so-useful itertools package.

```
    >>> {key: vals for i, (key, vals) in enumerate(dict_numbers.items()) 
        if key not in chain(*list(dict_numbers.values())[:i])}
    {'one': ['one', 'first', 'uno', 'une'], 
    'zero': ['zero', 'nothing', 'cero'], 
    'dos': ['two', 'second', 'dos', 'segundo', 'deux'], 
    'three': ['three', 'tres', 'third', 'tercero'], 
    'forth': ['four', 'forth', 'cuatro', 'cuarto']}
```

Essentially, this works by recreating the original dictionary for entries where there are no occurrence where the key is found in any of the preceding lists (hence the enumerate and slicing shenanigans).